# Closed Subset of a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Let (X, d) be a metric space, and suppose that A ⊂ X is a subset that satisfies
the following property:

$\exists$ δ > 0 such that d(x, y) > δ for all x, y ∈ A with x $\neq$ y.

I need to show that A is a closed subset of X.

I have tried to complete this by using the fact that A must be closed if the limit of a convergent sequence, which lies in A, is also in A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ be a convergent sequence in $A$ with limit point $x$. Then there is some $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $d(x_n, x) < \frac{\delta}{2}$ for all $N \le n \in \mathbb N$.

But now, for all $N \le m \le n \in \mathbb N$
$$
d(x_m,x_n) \le d(x_m, x) + d(x_n, x) < \delta
$$
and hence, by our assumption on $A$, $x_m = x_n$. Therefore $(x_n \mid n \in \mathbb N)$ is eventually constant and hence its limit (i.e. the eventually value of this sequence) is in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

A point $x$ is a limit point of the set $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point $y\neq x.$

But then $A$ contains all its limit points, since it has none, and so is closed. To see this, take an arbitrary $x\in A.$ Then $B(x,\delta/2)\cap A=\emptyset$ so $B(x,\delta/2)$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that contains no point from $A$ other than $x$ itself.